# Filter describe-images command results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I have a command that prints out all of my AMIs after a particular date. However, instead of printing everything about the AMI, I would like to print just the AMI's "image-id"

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters Name=description,Values=soft_ami --query "Images[?CreationDate>=`2016-09-25`][]" --output text > C:\amioutput.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters Name=description,Values=soft_ami --query "Images[?CreationDate>=`2016-09-25`][ImageId]" --output text > C:\amioutput.txt
```

You should read the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html).

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly.

Comment: You should mark your question as answered then. It gives Mark the credit and also tells others that answering your future questions is worh it ;-).